# Using "=" in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'd like to know why I get an error with my SWI Prolog when I try to do this:

```
(signal(X) = signal(Y)) :- (terminal(X), terminal(Y), connected(X,Y)).
terminal(X) :- ((signal(X) = 1);(signal(X) = 0)).
```

I get the following error

> Error: trabalho.pro:13: No permission to modify static procedure
>   '(=)/2'

It doesn't recognize the `"="` in the first line, but the second one "compiles". I guess it only accepts the `"="` after the `:-` ? Why?

Will I need to create a predicate like: `"equal(x,y) :- (x = y)"` for this?

Comment: just rename it `equal_signals(X,Y):- ...`. `=/2` is a system predicate, you can not and need not change it here.

Comment: `(Signal(t) = 1) OR ( Signal(t) = 0)` translates to Prolog as `signal(T,S), (S=1 ; S=0)`. this if you have a "function" `signal` which "returns" results in its 2nd argument. But you don't include any explanations in your questions, we're left guessing. Perhaps you could start by explaining what you have, in which "world" is your question set, and what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `=` is a predefined predicate. What you actually write is (the grounding of terms using the Martelli-Montanari algorithm):

```
=(signal(X),signal(Y)) :- Foo.
```

You use predicates like functions in Prolog.

You can define something like:

```
terminal(X) :- signal(X,1);signal(X,0).
```

where `signal/2` is a predicate that contains a key/value pair.

And:

```
equal_signal(X,Y) :- terminal(X),terminal(Y),connected(X,Y).
```

Comment: =(signal(X),signal(Y)) :- terminal(X),terminal(Y),connected(X,Y).
This? I got the same error...

Comment: Of course. What I say is that you aim to override a system predicate. It is not wise to do that. Furthermore you use `signal` as a function. Prolog uses the Herbrand universe. Therefore `signal(a)` is only equal to `signal(a)` (and not `0`, `1`, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. The only way to implement functions is like: signal(x,y)? and then i should check for Y value and create rules for it? thats what i found in internet. what i was trying to do is put these first order logic in prolog:  t1, t2  (Terminal(t1) and Terminal(t2) and Connected(t1, t2)) -> (Signal(t1) = Signal(t2))  - 
 t Terminal(t) -> (Signal(t) = 1) OR( Signal(t) = 0)

Comment: Well, as far as I know, one cannot do this (unless of course you write you're own meta-compiler in Prolog). Functions are indeed implemented using a predicate `p/2` with `(x,y)` tuples. Notice that this is a map and that for instance a key `x` can have multiple `y`s

Answer (score 1):

Diedre - there are no 'functions' in Prolog. There are predicates. The usual pattern
goes

name(list of args to be unified)  :-  body of predicate .

Usually you'd want the thing on the left side of the :- operator to be a predicate
name. when you write

(signal(X) = signal(Y))

= is an operator, so you get

'='(signal(X), signal(Y))

But (we assume, it's not clear what you're doing here) that you don't really want to change equals.
Since '=' is already in the standard library, you can't redefine it (and wouldn't want to)

What you probably want is

equal_signal(X, Y) :-  ... bunch of stuff... .
or

equal_signal(signal(X), signal(Y)) :-  ... bunch of stuff ... .

This seems like a conceptual error problem. You need to have a conversation with somebody who understands it. I might humbly suggest you pop onto ##prolog on freenode.net or 
some similar forum and get somebody to explain it.

Comment: I m studying logic in artificial inteligence, but ive never used prolog. Im seeing that prolog language is kite differente to first order logic in syntax. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Yes - Prolog is based on Horn Clauses, a subset of first order logic.

Comment: In my opinion, that's not the fundamental aspect that makes Prolog different from first order logic: the negation as finite failure, minimal model, closed-world assumption, Herbrand modelling, are quite different as well.